# ¿Cómo podría pasar el precio en un formulario de actualización?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, localhost

Trataré de explicarme lo mejor posible. Actualmente realizo un sistema de inventario en el cual implemente un CRUD, pero en la parte de actualizar le producto, me trae la información, pero al oprimir el botón de actualizar no me ejecuta la acción les pondré imágenes y el código.

Aquí podrán ver que me trae la información del formulario al pulsar el botón:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLEbm.png

Al pulsar el botón actualizar:
Eso es lo que me aparece al parecer tengo un error en la sintaxis de MYSQL:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5Ln6.png

Ahora les pondré el código del formulario:

```
<?php 
    include("../conexiones/conectar.php");
    $con=conectar();

$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM ropa WHERE id='$id'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Formulario de Actualización</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/registrar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pin.it/3urbp4j" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <selection class="form-register">
      <div class="container mt-5">
        <h4>Edita tú Producto</h4>
        <form action="../procesadores/update-ropa.php" method="POST">
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="date"
            name="fecha"
            placeholder="Fecha" 
            value="<?php echo $row['fecha']  ?>"
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="clave"
            placeholder="Clave"
            maxlength="6"
            autofocus
            value="<?php echo $row['clave']  ?>"
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="nombre_producto"
            placeholder="Nombre del Producto"
            maxlength="30"
            value="<?php echo $row['nombre_producto']  ?>"
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="descripcion"
            placeholder="Descripcion"
            maxlength="60"
            value="<?php echo $row['descripcion']  ?>"
          />
          <select name="genero" class="controls">
            <option disabled="">Elije un genero</option>
            <option value="Mujer">Mujer</option>
            <option value="Hombre">Hombre</option>
            <option value="Unisex">Unisex</option>
            value="<?php echo $row['genero']  ?>"
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="marca">
            <option disabled="">Elije una marca</option>
            <option value="Quiubolee!">Quiubolee!</option>
            <option value="Varios">Varios</option>
            <option value="Pókemon">Pókemon</option>
            <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="Lenovo">Lenovo</option>
            <option value="Star wars">Star wars</option>
            <option value="Body Balance">Body Balance</option>
            <option value="Xiaomi">Xiaomi</option>
            <option value="Huawei">Huawei</option>
            <option value="Iwo">Iwo</option>
            <option value="MultiMarca">MultiMarca</option>
            <option value="Lbel">Lbel</option>
            <option value="Esika">Esika</option>
            <option value="Cyzone">Cyzone</option>
            value="<?php echo $row['marca']  ?>"
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="categoria">
            <option disabled="">Elije una categoria</option>
            <option value="Ropa">Ropa</option>
            <option value="Calcetines">Calcetines</option>
            <option value="Tecnologia">Tecnologia</option>
            <option value="Llavero">Llavero</option>
            <option value="Cartera">Cartera</option>
            <option value="Billetera">Billetera</option>
            <option value="Funda">Funda</option>
            <option value="Lampara">Lampara</option>
            <option value="Encendedor">Encendedor</option>
            <option value="Coleccionables">Iwo</option>
            <option value="Correas">Correas</option>
            <option value="BodyConcept">BodyConcept</option>
            <option value="Almohadas">Almohadas</option>
            <option value="Cyzone">Cyzone</option>
            <option value="Monedero">Monedero</option>
            <option value="Hogar">Hogar</option>
            <option value="Accesorios">Accesorios</option>
            <option value="Maquillaje">Maquillaje</option>
            <option value="Accesorios">Accesorios</option>
            <option value="Perfumes">Perfumes</option>
            value="<?php echo $row['categoria']  ?>"
          </select>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="tipo">
            <option disabled="">Elije un tipo</option>
            <option value="Playera">Playera</option>
            <option value="Short">Short</option>
            <option value="Sudadera">Sudadera</option>
            <option value="Pants">Pants</option>
            <option value="Mamelucos">Mamelucos</option>
            <option value="Frazada/Cobijas">Frazadas/Cobijas</option>
            value="<?php echo $row['tipo']  ?>"
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="talla">
            <option disabled="">Elije una talla</option>
            <option value="SS">SS</option>
            <option value="S">S</option>
            <option value="M">M</option>
            <option value="G">G</option>
            <option value="XL">XL</option>
            <option value="Sin talla">Sin talla</option>
            value="<?php echo $row['talla']  ?>"
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="color" required>
            <option disabled="">Elije un color</option>
            <option value="Azul">Azul</option>
            <option value="Rojo">Rojo</option>
            <option value="Amarillo">Amarillo</option>
            <option value="Cafe">Cafe</option>
            <option value="Naranja">Naranja</option>
            <option value="Rosa">Rosa</option>
            <option value="Morado">Morado</option>
            <option value="Violeta">Violeta</option>
            <option value="Rosa Fucsia">Rosa Fucsia</option>
            <option value="Azul celeste">Azul celeste</option>
            <option value="Azul oscuro">Azul oscuro</option>
            <option value="Azul claro">Azul claro</option>
            <option value="Negro">Negro</option>
            <option value="Blanco">Blanco</option>
            <option value="Girs">Girs</option>
            <option value="Marrón">Marrón</option>
            <option value="MultiColor">MultiColor</option>
            value="<?php echo $row['color']  ?>"
          </select>
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="unidades"
            placeholder="Unidades"
            maxlength="11"
            value="<?php echo $row['unidades']  ?>"
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="number"
            step="any"
            name="p_compra"
            placeholder="Precio de Compra"
            value="<?php echo $row['p_compra']  ?>"
          />

          <input
            type="submit"
            class="button"
            value="Actualizar"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </selection>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y aquí podrán observar el código del procesador:

```
<?php

include("../conexiones/conectar.php");
$con=conectar();

$fecha=$_POST["fecha"]; 
$clave=$_POST["clave"];  
$nombre_producto=$_POST["nombre_producto"]; 
$descripcion=$_POST["descripcion"]; 
$genero=$_POST["genero"];  
$marca=$_POST["marca"];  
$categoria=$_POST["categoria"];
$tipo=$_POST["tipo"];
$talla=$_POST["talla"]; 
$color=$_POST["color"]; 
$unidades=$_POST["unidades"]; 
$p_compra=$_POST["p_compra"];
```

$sql="UPDATE ropa SET fecha='$fecha',nombre_producto='$nombre_producto',descripcion='$descripcion', genero='$genero', categoria='$categoria', tipo='$tipo', talla='$talla', color='$color', unidades='$unidades', p_compra='$p_compra', WHERE clave='$calve'";

```
 $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    
    if($query){
        Header("Location: ../pages/ropa.php");
    }
?>
```

Quisiera saber como pasar la cantidad del precio de compra tal cual, si es que hay forma o no sé cual sería la forma correcta de ponerlo en mi código.

**Ahora modificando la parte con la comilla, hace que todos los valores que ya tenia agregados en la tabla, sean todos los mismo, entonces leí acerca que se le agrega el** *WHERE*:

```
<?php

include("../conexiones/conectar.php");
$con=conectar();

$fecha=$_POST["fecha"]; 
$clave=$_POST["clave"];  
$nombre_producto=$_POST["nombre_producto"]; 
$descripcion=$_POST["descripcion"]; 
$genero=$_POST["genero"];  
$marca=$_POST["marca"];  
$categoria=$_POST["categoria"];
$tipo=$_POST["tipo"];
$talla=$_POST["talla"]; 
$color=$_POST["color"]; 
$unidades=$_POST["unidades"]; 
$p_compra=$_POST["p_compra"];


$sql="UPDATE ropa SET fecha='$fecha',nombre_producto='$nombre_producto',descripcion='$descripcion', genero='$genero', categoria='$categoria', tipo='$tipo', talla='$talla', color='$color', unidades='$unidades', p_compra='$p_compra', WHERE clave='$clave'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if($query){
        Header("Location: ../pages/ropa.php");
    }
?>
```

Pero ahora me aparece lo siguiente:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3AOM.png

Answer (score 0):

Estuve leyendo tu código y parece que te falta una comilla simple el `$sql` después de `$unidades` y eso hace que se corte la cadena, Prueba con esto y verifica también que en tu tabla "ropa" el atributo "p_compra" este de tipo doble y al actulizar tienes que usar WHERE y el codigo que tiene ese producto `where=id_producto`:

```
$sql="UPDATE ropa SET fecha='$fecha',nombre_producto='$nombre_producto',descripcion='$descripcion', genero='$genero', categoria='$categoria', tipo='$tipo', talla='$talla', color='$color', unidades='$unidades', p_compra='$p_compra', clave='$clave'";
```

Comment: Si efectivamente era la comilla, muchas gracias. Te lo agradezco. Aunque ahora me cambio todos los valores de la tabla al mismo. Por ejemplo todos los productos que tenía se cambiaron al nombre que estaba actualizando :(.

Comment: Si para ello puedes utiliza el `where=id_producto`  para que así seleccione solo el producto que quieras cambiar

Comment: Aunque no esté pasando por id?. Lo intentaré, muchas gracias Jhefferson. Ya lo lo hice, pero arroja el mismo error, con la sintaxis.                     $sql="UPDATE ropa SET fecha='$fecha',nombre_producto='$nombre_producto',descripcion='$descripcion', genero='$genero', categoria='$categoria', tipo='$tipo', talla='$talla', color='$color', unidades='$unidades', p_compra='$p_compra', WHERE=clave'";

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que antes de ejecutar directamente del PHP intentes probar tu consulta en el MySQL,  por lo que ve en tu `$sql` es que tienes una coma antes del  `WHERE clave='$clave'"`. Recuerda que es una cadena y si la cadena no funciona en el MySQL no funcionará en el PHP

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a probarlo antes ne MySQL, tu consejo lo tendré muy en cuenta. Y si era eso, te agradezco mucho.